# Hotels.com booking with debit card

Tags: bookings, payment-cards, refunds

I have booked an apartment in Benidorm from Monday 25 to June 3rd of this year and I booked this with a debit card, but since booking I had to get a replacement card and was wondering if I try and cancel the booking I have, how can my money get refunded into my new debit card?

Comment: Why do you think cancellation is necessary? Because you used a debit card, the funds to pay hotel.com would have been taken from your account at the time you booked.

Comment: Yeah but due to the crisis happening right now there is no point going on the trip, so I will need to cancel it. I am just saying I now have a new card, but they have the info of my old card and already have taken money out.

Comment: You might start by asking your financial institution what'll happen if a previous charge is reversed and a credit applied to your old card number. In the credit card world, the card numbers remain "connected." I don't know if things are different in the debit card world.

Comment: When I had recent offers to refunds due to cancelations the texts mentioned 'to the accounts connected to the payment cards used.' So if your new card is a replacement for the same account I expect it to work.